# Error when instantiating a UIFont in an text attributes dictionary

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, compiler-errors, uibarbuttonitem

I'm trying to set the font of the `UIBarButtonItem` like so:

```
let barButton = UIBarButtonItem.appearance()
barButton.setTitleTextAttributes([NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "AvenirNext", size: 15], forState: UIControlState.Normal)
```

But it throws a compiler error saying:

> Cannot invoke 'init' with an argument list type '($T7, forState: UIControlState)`

and I have no idea what that means. I have also tried

```
barButton.titleTextAttributesForState(UIControlState.Normal) =[NSFontAttributeName...]`
```

but it appears that it isn't assignable

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The initializer of `UIFont` returns an optional because it may fail due to misspelled font name etc.

You have to unwrap it and check:

```
if let font = UIFont(name: "AvenirNext", size: 15) {
    barButton.setTitleTextAttributes([NSFontAttributeName: font], forState: UIControlState.Normal)
}
```

**UPDATED for Swift 3**

```
if let font = UIFont(name: "AvenirNext", size: 15) {
    barButton.setTitleTextAttributes([NSFontAttributeName:font], for: .normal)
}
```

Comment: Still throwing that error... And this syntax worked for me until I updated to Xcode 6.1

Comment: This solved my problem, but I too had never seen this issue before 6.1.

Answer (score 2):

Setting Custom font is little bit tricky, since they don't have `font` and `title` properties. Hope this following answer will help you.

```
let font = UIFont(name: "<your_custom_font_name>", size: <font_size>)
var leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "<font_hex_code>", style: UIBarButtonStyle.Plain, target: self, action: "buttonClicked:")
leftBarButtonItem.setTitleTextAttributes([NSFontAttributeName:font!], forState: UIControlState.Normal)
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = leftBarButtonItem
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if let font : UIFont = UIFont(name: "Roboto-Regular", size: 15)
        {
            cancelBarButton.setTitleTextAttributes([NSFontAttributeName: font], forState: UIControlState.Normal)
            doneBarButton.setTitleTextAttributes([NSFontAttributeName: font], forState: UIControlState.Normal)

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

**With Swift 4**

**NSFontAttributeName is deprecated**, you can use NSAttributedStringKey values to set attributes.

```
if let fontStyle = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Light", size: 19) {
 navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.font: fontStyle]
```

}