# How to change UIBarButtonItem title size in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I want to change the UIBarButtonItem.title size , I am using 2 different code lines below:

```
let font = UIFont(name:"Arial", size: 8)        
     newBarButtonItem.setTitleTextAttributes([NSFontAttributeName:font],forState: UIControlState.Normal)


 newBarButtonItem.setTitleTextAttributes([NSFontAttributeName:UIFont(name:"Arial", size: 8)],forState: UIControlState.Normal)
```

When I run the application, button title does not change. Can anyone help me about this. Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26483671/customizing-uibarbuttonitem-in-swift

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
if let font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 13) {
            barBtn.setTitleTextAttributes([NSFontAttributeName: font], forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it globally:

```
if let font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 10) {
                UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSFontAttributeName : font], forState: .Normal)
            }
```